# disabling css styles for specific styles for IE9

Tags: css, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9, stylesheet

How to disable specific styles only for IE9. My design needs transformations and IE9 does not support it, I need to disable them and use the jQuery transform().

Is there any prefix or something with which I can disable certain styles only in IE9?

Comment: Found Sort of solution: Remove the classes using jquery's removeClass() then do the animation.

Comment: Any other approaches would be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise you to use CONDITIONAL COMMENTS (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512.ASPX).

You can create a separate CSS file for your IE9 workarounds to avoid browsers that support styles that aren't supported in IE9 from downloading your css file. thus resulting on a faster load time.

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
  <link href='yourstylesheet' rel='stylesheet'/>
<![endif]-->
```